# Rails 5 how to add the HH:MM (string) in created_at?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, time

I have time in string formats 05:50(Hours: Minutes) I want to add that to the created_at(Wed, 16 Nov 2016 14:04:37 IST +05:30) field in the database.

I need something like 14:04:37(HH:MM:SS) + 05:50(HH:MM)

I have tried it with the strftime methods but not succeeded.

How can I do that?

Comment: that is the business rule I need to follow.

Comment: I just need to add the time in the created_at field so can I convert both of them into seconds and then add them?

Comment: @max - asked what the OP was trying to accomplish and received the equivalent of "Because" (aka "that is the business rule I need to follow").  That I bothered to respond was because I had a long process running.  Won't make that mistake again.

Answer (score 0):

Use an [ActiveSupport::Duration](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Duration.html#method-c-build):

```
string = '05:50'  
duration = ActiveSupport::Duration.parse(
  # converts string into a ISO8601 duration
  "PT" + ['H', 'M'].zip(string.split(':')).join  
)
puts duration.since(model.created_at) # 5 hours and 50 minutes in the future
```

Not that this doesn't actually update anything as your question is extremely vague. If you want to update existing records you would need to call:

```
model.update(created_at: duration.since(model.created_at))
```

For new records you might be able to use a callback to change it during the lifecycle:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  attribute_accessor :advance_by
  before_validate :advance_created_at, if: ->{ advance_by.present? }

  private
  def advance_created_at
    duration = ActiveSupport::Duration.parse(
        # converts string into a ISO8601 duration
        "PT" + ['H', 'M'].zip(@advance_by.split(':')).join  
    )
    self.advance_by = nil # prevents this from happening repeatedly
    self.created_at = duration.since(created_at)
  end
end
```